# I want to find only Lecturer list using case expression

Tags: sql, postgresql

Here is my code:

```
select first_name, salary, dept,  
case when salary >= 50000 and (dept = 'Lecturer') then 'Lecturers'
else 'None' end as "Lecturer List" from friend;
```

I want to print the list of lecturers only. But the information of all other departments is also coming. How to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

Since you only want to see lecturers in the result set, you may simply move the filtering logic in your `CASE` expression to the `WHERE` clause:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM yourTable
WHERE salary >= 50000 AND dept = 'Lecturer';
```

Comment: But also I want them in another column named "Lecturer List" where it's easy to look at the lecturer's list. I trying put your code under case expression but not working.

Comment: Then just do `SELECT *, 'Lecturer List' AS label ...` since every record in the result set would be a lecturer, therefore we can simply select a string constant.